# Opencart 2.3.0.2 how to change default index.php?route=common/home to index.php?route=magikblog/article

Tags: php, opencart

I have a problem if anyone could help
I would like to change the default `index.php?route=common/home` to `index.php?route=magikblog/article` cos I want the visitor visit my blog first before they drive to another part of my site.
Please help! Thanks

Comment: *Xorifelse looks into his magic 8-ball*, Your question is [hazy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please try again.

Answer (score 1):

The 'common/home' default routing in set in a config file:

> /system/config/default.php

under the default actions variables set

```
// Actions
$_['action_default'] = 'common/home';
```

Simply change the route to

```
// Actions
$_['action_default'] = 'magikblog/article';
```

or to any other preferred routing

Answer (score 0):

in file **controller/common/home.php**

$this->redirect(HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=magikblog/article');
its just small hook but can resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the answers above it really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer is good, but I'd suggest you to add your article to the home page and don't change the redirect. You can use a module for that (if any) or simply write a portion of text on the homepage, if you're not going to change the text in the future.