# opencart 3 - redirect home page to category

Tags: redirect, opencart, categories

[Edit: corrected typo]
I want category (index.php?route=product/category&path=1) on home page of Opencart 3

I have tested several methods without success:

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=18952 (10years old)
Didnt work editing file /catalog/controller/common/home.php and ading redirect:
`$this->redirect(HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/category&path=1');`

[Opencart 2.3.0.2 how to change default index.php?route=common/home to index.php?route=magikblog/article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446020/opencart-2-3-0-2-how-to-change-default-index-phproute-common-home-to-index-php) (4 years old)
Didnt help changing
`$_['action_default'] = 'common/home';`
to `$_['action_default'] = 'product/category&path=1';`
or `$_['action_default'] = 'category_id=1';` (this last work in SEO page without problem)

Please where I make it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this on top index() method of catalog\controller\common\home.php

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=1'));
return
```

Comment: Im sorry for delay, Yes it works like charm, realy thank you.